# Decoupling PDEs in non diagonalizable case

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I know that Linear Hyperbolic PDE systems can be decoupled(at least the principal part) but can a PDE system be decoupled if the eigenvalues are real i.e not elliptic but the matrix is non diagonalizable??

Comment: If the Jordan normal form is still applicable, then could that be a possibility? I don't have much broad knowledge on PDEs. But, if you give an example, I would like to try it out.

Comment: @Raaja Here is an example    $\vec{u}_{t}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & -4 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\vec{u}_{x}=0 $    the matrix has only one eigenvalue i.e 2.\\ Thanks for the idea(I forgot about jordon form completely from my course never thought it would be useful but alas! i was wrong )The jordan normal form does help in this case.$J=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $It allows me to solve for u_2 independently of u_{1} and then i can put it in the first equation to get u_{1}.Again,thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!